# Validator failing for not defined param

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, request, get

I am using [Validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/Validator) to validate the http request with a defined rule. I have added one rule for GET requests that checks the value of the `mode` in the input parameter.`mode` is not a required input parameter.

```
 getGameModes: {
    mode: `in:${GAME_MODES.COMPETITIVE},${GAME_MODES.FRIENDLY},${GAME_MODES.TUTORIAL}`
  }
```

Validator works properly for following request, throw errors if not satisfy the rule definition or return success.

```
http://localhost:3000/getGameModes?mode=COMPETITIVE
http://localhost:3000/getGameModes?mode=COMPETITIVE&someOther=test
http://localhost:3000/getGameModes?mode=NOT_EXISTS_MODE
http://localhost:3000/getGameModes
```

But the validator fails and throw the error for the below request where the mode parameter does not exist in the request but we have other params in the request (`someOther`)

```
http://localhost:3000/getGameModes?someOther=test
```

Error

```
"message": "The selected mode is invalid."
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? I want to apply the rule only when the request parameter contains the `mode` parameter in the request.

Comment: Looking at Laravel's doc it has validator called `sometimes` which you can use like `mode: \`sometimes | in:${GAME_MODES.COMPETITIVE}, ..other modes\``

Comment: @CodeThing, still getting same error. rule - ``` mode: `sometimes|in:${GAME_MODES.COMPETITIVE},${GAME_MODES.FRIENDLY},${GAME_MODES.TUTORIAL}```
`

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding custom validation if the `sometimes` rule doesn't work for you. In the doc they have example of using custom rule.

So you can try something like this.

```
const getGameModes = {
    mode: 'gamemode' // Instead of **in** we use custom rule here 
};

// Callback to handle custom rule
function validateGameMode(name, value, params) {
  const validGameModes = [GAME_MODES.COMPETITIVE, GAME_MODES.FRIENDLY, GAME_MODES.TUTORIAL];
  return (value !== '') ? validGameModes.includes(value) : true;
}

const v = Validator.make(data, getGameModes);
// custom rule definition
v.extend('gamemode', validateGameMode, ':attr is not a valid game mode');
```